# Why does fork sometimes return parent and sometimes child?

Tags: process, fork

When running the `fork` call to create a new process, if it succeed it returns either `0` (the child) or the parent.

I didn't get the idea behind this. Why doesn't `fork` just always return `child` or always `parent`?

Comment: It always returns _both_, unless it fails.

Comment: It may be instructive to [read the specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html)

Comment: As a programmer convenience to tell whether the code following the fork() should act as the parent or the child without needing to check the process id, etc. Because a parent needs to keep track of the child and handle exits to prevent zombies, and the child needs to do the thing it was invoked for.

Comment: Do you actually know what `fork` *does*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you `fork()`, the code that’s running finds itself running in two processes (assuming the fork is successful): one process is the parent, the other the child. `fork()` returns 0 in the child process, and the child pid in the parent process: it’s entirely deterministic.

This is how you can determine, after the `fork()`, whether you’re running in the parent or the child. (And also how the parent knows the child pid — it needs to wait on it at some point.)

In a little more detail:

- the future parent process calls `fork()`;
- the kernel creates a new process, which is the child, and sets various things up appropriately — but both processes are running *the same code* and are “waiting” for a return from the same function;
- *both processes continue running* (not necessarily straight away, and not necessarily simultaneously, but that’s besides the point):

  - `fork()` returns 0 to the child process, which continues and uses that information to determine that it’s the child;
  - `fork()` returns the child pid to the parent process, which continues and uses that information to determine that it’s the parent.

Comment: the `fork is executed by the parent process. so I thought we still  the parent process and we always get `pid` of the child. I dont get the idea of how the current process running fork can become the child process (case it returns 0)

Comment: @MakhloufGharbi It duplicates the process context. That's what it's for.

Comment: @Makhlouf `fork()` starts a new process, but it doesn’t tell the kernel “here, start a new process and run this piece of code in it” — both the current and the new process continue running the same code.

Comment: @Makhlouf imagine if you suddenly spawned an identical twin, with all your memories etc., doing exactly the same thing as you are — how would you know which is the original, and which is the newly-spawned twin?

Comment: @StephenKitt Well, clearly I am the original (and me too)

Comment: The child can do *getpid()* to know its own pid, the parent however would have a hard time finding the pid of its child if *fork()* didn't return it.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Reminiscent of “Learning to Be Me” in [Greg Egan's Axiomatic](https://www.amazon.com/Axiomatic-Short-Stories-Science-Fiction/dp/1597805408)

Answer (score 4):

The `fork()` system call "returns twice", always (unless it fails).  In the parent, it returns the PID of the child process, and in the child, it returns zero.

The usual flow is

```
pid_t pid;
int status;

pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
  run_child_stuff();
  exit(0);
} else if (pid > 0) {
  run_parent_stuff();
  wait(&status); /* wait for child to exit */
} else {
  /* handle failure to fork */
}
```

... or similar.