# How does a parent process know the process IDs of the child processes it started?

Tags: process, signals, fork

The title was a question in an exam I had recently.
I could not find the answer afterwards in the slides (also not on the web).
In the course slides it is only described that the parent process holds the PIDs of its child process but not **how** it received them.

My guess is that transmission of the IDs is directly done with the fork command or afterwards through signals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My guess is that transmission of the IDs is directly done with the fork command or afterwards through signals.

It’s the former: `fork()` returns the child PID to the parent. See [Why does fork sometimes return parent and sometimes child?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/361713/86440) for more detail (and [`man 2 fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) of course, and the [POSIX definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html)).

A process can find its parent’s PID using the [`getppid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getppid.2.html) system call (also defined [by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getppid.html)).